# Hide video except for website use?

Tags: youtube

I have a video that I'd like to have available on my website, but will be irrelevant or even annoying to my general followers.

Is there a YouTube-supported way to upload without my users seeing it on their timelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload the video as "Unlisted". It won't be visible to everyone, just the folks have the link can watch it. Embedding the link in your website should be fine, visitors to your site will be able to watch the video